# Removing UIView from Super View on Main Thread Still Does Not Remove View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code to add and then remove a UIView based on some conditions. The noItemsView removeFromSuperView line is called but I can still see the view on the screen. Am I doing something wrong?

```
@interface PantryTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *_pantryItems;
    NoItemsView *_noItemsView;
}
@end

**PantryTableViewController: viewDidLoad:** 

  _noItemsView = [[NoItemsView alloc] initWithMessage:@"Opps! No Items in the Pantry!"];

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if(_pantryItems.count == 0) {

        [self.view addSubview:_noItemsView];
    }
    else
    {
        // this line gets invoked but the view is still displayed on the
        // screen
        [_noItemsView removeFromSuperview];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

});
```

**SOLUTION:**

Missing the if check for creating an instance of the noItemsView as shown below:

```
if(!_noItemsView)
{
 _noItemsView = [[NoItemsView alloc] initWithMessage:@"Opps! No Items in the Pantry!"];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intending to remove a `noItemsView` that already exists on screen? If so, you need to store it in a property, instead of a scope variable like this.

Comment: I created a private field for it but still it was not removing. Will using a property instead of private field make a difference?

Comment: Private field? The logic in your block of code doesn't make sense. By this approach you would only allocate and add a subview when _pantryItems.count == 0. The else is redundant.

Comment: Ideally you would want something like `if (!self.noItemsView) self.noItemsView = ...; [self.view addSubview:self.noItemsView];` OR `[self.noItemsView removeFromSuperview]`;

Comment: Sorry! updated the original code. I moved the _noItemsView ivar into the header file instead of exposing it as property.

Comment: You're still creating a new instance of `noItemsView` every time.

Comment: Thanks Ricky! That was it.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new instance of `UIView` and trying to remove which is never been added to view.
You have to find the instance of `UIView` from superview and then remove from memory.

You should try this way.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

if(_pantryItems.count == 0) {
 NoItemsView *noItemsView = [[NoItemsView alloc] initWithMessage:@"Opps! No Items in the Pantry!"];
[self.view addSubview:noItemsView];
}
else
{

// screen
for(UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
  {
     If([ view isKindOfClass:[NoItemsView Class]){
         [view removeFromSuperview];
          view = nil;
         }
     }
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I haven't compiled the code I just typed from my phone but this should be logic.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution helped me find a solution. I posted the solution in the original question. Thanks!